# Custom Domain on Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I would like to setup a custom domain for Cognito.( it's on App Integration -> Domain Name). I am trying to follo this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-add-custom-domain.html#cognito-user-pools-add-custom-domain-adding, but I am little bit confused on step 3.

> On step 3: To set up a custom domain name or to update its
>   certificate, you must have permission to update Amazon CloudFront
>   distributions. You can do so by attaching the following IAM policy
>   statement to an IAM user, group, or role in your AWS account:

I need to "attach" a permission for Cognito to create a Cloud Front Distribuition, but the documentation didn't say how to do it.

I have created a role with trust relantionship for cognito id... But it's still not able to create cloud front...And no error message...

Comment: You need to attach that role to your own IAM user account which you will use to create a Cloud Front Distribuition using the AWS console.

Comment: Are u sure? I am using a root account...

Comment: If you are using the root account then you won't need to make that policy. Did you run into any errors following the rest of the steps?

Comment: I didnt run into any errors. The cloudfront just didn't appear, so I was not able to define an alias pointing to it.

Comment: Well the docs you linked only tell you how to use an existing distribution. You will have to create one first. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-creating.html

Comment: @NinadGaikwad I don't think so.  *"Note the Alias target. Instead of an IP address or a domain name, the Alias target is an alias resource record set that points to an Amazon CloudFront distribution."*  It sounds like Cognito may be creating one for you, in one of its own accounts, and handing over the endpoint to you to use in DNS, similar to what API Gateway does in some cases.  The CloudFront distribution is both invisible in the console, and free, if this is indeed the case.

Comment: @p.magalhaes did you see an alias target as described in step 10?